# Bokeh - use widgets at runtime to change the data displayed on the figure

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using Bokeh with Python to create output from my Pandas dataframe. I can pass to the figure the fields I want to display; but if I want to display different fields in the dataframe, I have to change the code and then run the function again.

This is how I display the graph (for sake of simplicity I am not adding the dataframe; which contains a lot of fields)

```
x_field = pd.data['names'].tolist()
y_field = pd.data['age'].tolist()

p=figure(plot_width=800, ploth_height=600, title="test", x_axis_label="names", y_axis_label="age", x_range=x_field)
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 0.78
p.vbar(top=y_field, x=x_field, width=0.5)
show(p)
```

I did discover that Bokeh has widgets; so I was able to create a radio button group, and add it to a layout

```
radio_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["test1", "test2"], active=0)
layout = row(widgetbox(radio_group), p)
show(layout)
```

This does show the widget but I have no connection with it. How do you connect the widget so it will get events when I push the buttons?

I did find on a tutorial the reference to the `update` function, but it never get called. Also I do not see how do you "refresh" a figure; looking into examples now and it is not immediate to me.

EDIT--------------------------

I did find out that you need to use the Bokeh server to have interactive graphs; the other alternative is to use `CustomJS` to call JS code inside your Python function; although the figure does not seem to be updating, even if the code is correctly executed.

Not sure if this is an issue with Bokeh or something else, but I am still looking to find the source of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Widgets are only able to call update functions when used on a Bokeh server. 
They can only be used to call [CustomJS](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#javascript-callbacks) callbacks when you aren't using a Bokeh server.

On [this](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#single-module-format) page you can find an example of an update function that is called when the user clicks on a button and more information about Bokeh servers.

Comment: I see, so I must use JS to run any action on these widgets, if I do not run a server. The idea is to output the page as HTML; for some reasons I assumed that the code to handle widgets was already in Bokeh, so when the HTML page is loaded, I could access the API and change dataset on the fly with widgets.